# Scale_color_manual only show one color in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, legend

I created a line graph with a series of data using ggplot in RStudio. My legend is only showing one color, always the last one where the geom_line used show.legend=TRUE. In this case the colors in the legend are all green. What am I missing? Here is the code:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = Q1Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments)) + geom_line(data = Q1Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments), color="blue", show.legend = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(data = Q2Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments)) + geom_line(data = Q2Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments), color="purple", show.legend = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(data = Q3Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments)) + geom_line(data = Q3Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments), color="orange", show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = Q4Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments)) + geom_line(data = Q4Shipments, mapping = aes(x=Year, y=Shipments), color="green", show.legend = TRUE) +
  ylim(3500, 5000) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size = 15)) + 
  ggtitle("Shipments Per Quarter By Year") + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, size = 15)) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Quarters", breaks=c("Q1Shipments", "Q2Shipments", "Q3Shipments", "Q4Shipments"), values=c("Q1Shipments"="blue", "Q2Shipments"="purple", "Q3Shipments"="orange", "Q4Shipments"="green"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvaT0.png)

Comment: Color needs to be inside `aes`.

Comment: Try with `geom_line(data = Q1Shipments, aes(x=Year, y=Shipments, color="Q1Shipments"))` and so on. This will automatically add a legend and assign the color you have specified for `Q1Shipments` in scale_color_manual.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan and Andrew.  Solved!